# Rubywarrior Level 4 (cleaning up my code help)

Tags: ruby, code-cleanup

I'm learning programming through Ruby and I found the awesome Rubywarrior by Ryan Bates from Railscasts. Unfortunately I'm stuck in that my code is throwing up syntax error messages (unexpected $end).

I'm not asking for the answer, I would like to sort that out myself, but if someone could point out where my code is getting the error from that would be super. Thanks!

```
class Player

  def initialize
    @maxhealth = 20
    @dying = 7
    @previoushealth = @maxhealth
    @health = warrior.health
    @warrior = warrior
  end

  def play_turn(warrior)
  # If there are no enemies, rest until health is 100%
    turn_start_check(warrior)
    actions(warrior)
    turn_end_check(warrior)
  end

  def actions(warrior)
    if @damaged_since_last_turn
      warrior.shoot!
    elsif
      @health < @maxhealth
        warrior.rest!
    else
      warrior.walk!
    end
  end

  def hurt?(warrior)
    warrior.health < 20
  end

  def healthy?(warrior)
    warrior.health = 20
  end

  def alone?(warrior)
    warrior.feel.empty?
  end

  def should_i_move?(warrior)
    if healthy? and alone?
      warrior.rest!
    else
      warrior.walk!
  end

  # Put code here for if health from previous turn is less than last term
  # If true don't rest and keep moving forward
  def turn_start_check(warrior)
    @damaged_since_last_turn = @previoushealth > warrior.health
  end

  def turn_end_check(warrior)
    @previoushealth = warrior.health
  end
end
```

Comment: Your code looks very clean for someone learning Ruby (which is great!) but you might find it useful for your sanity to put the condition on the same line as the `elsif` in your `actions` method. That way the structure is the same as your `if` statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess:

```
def should_i_move?(warrior)
  if healthy? and alone?
    warrior.rest!
  else
    warrior.walk!
  end  # <<MISSING THIS ONE
end
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't want to give him the answer :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm still getting used to this whole "end" business since I've learnt some Python. Darn whitespaces.

Comment: :-] it messes me up a little bit too - i'm coming to ruby from perl, so i expect to see {}s. Plus the syntax errors are not what i would expect. For example, in your case, it says "unexpected $end" instead of "missing end".

Comment: The one I get from time to time is "unexpected end, expecting : " which throws me.

Answer (score 4):

That error message means that you are missing an `end` keyword somewhere. Check your code to see if all your statements are properly written.

Answer (score 1):

With Ruby 1.9.3, if you turn on warnings, you get the following warnings:

```
-:46: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'if' at 42
-:57: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'def' at 41
```

and then the error

```
-:57: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

line 46 corresponds to the first `end` after `def should_i_move?(warrior)`

This should work with earlier versions of Ruby 1.9 as well.