# Project Euler: Riddle 4 - What is my Ruby code doing?

Tags: ruby

I'm ***NOT*** asking for a solution to this riddle.

So, I'm working through the Project Euler problems using Ruby.

I made a palindrome checker with the following method:

```
def is_palindrome(n)
  if n.to_s == n.to_s.reverse
      true
  else
      false
  end
end
```

Using this, I use the next method to try and find the largest palindrome made with two 3 digit numbers.

```
x = 999
y = 998

while y > 100
  if is_palindrome(x * y) == true
    puts (x * y)
  else
    x-=1
    y-=1
  end
end
```

The result is the terminal throws a complete fit and gets stuck on 289982 and has to be Ctrl+C'd for it to stop.

As I said, I'm not looking for a solution to this riddle, but I want to know what it is my code is doing for this to happen. I'm still learning so my code is likely to be rather ugly, so extra karma points to anyone that can help me out with this.

Comment: Did you know there is a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site? That's a good forum for the code style part of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case a palindrome is found, you don't decrement your variables. Since the variables remain the same, the same palindrome is found again. And so it goes...

Comment: No worries. If you say you're looking for just the largest palindrome, you probably want to exit the loop immediately after you find your target. If using a `while` loop, you can do it with `break` statement. If you do want the rest of them, just take the decrement out of the `else`.

Answer (score 4):

Amadan's solved your problem, so I'll go for the extra karma points :)

First thing, you can just do `if something` instead of `if something == true`.

Also, you don't need to do

```
if something == something_else
  true
else
  false
end
```

because the `==` operator returns either `true` or `false` already, so your `is_palindrome` method could be as simple as

```
def is_palindrome(n)
  n.to_s == n.to_s.reverse
end
```

Also, in Ruby, you will usually see methods like this one (a boolean check) named with a question mark at the end, because it's really like you're asking it a yes/no question! So usually you'd see that called `is_palindrome?(n)`. Similar ones you might see elsewhere are `Array#empty?` and `Hash#has_key?(k)`.

Comment: ahaha same thought. It burned my eyes

Comment: Apologies for any eye burnings. I'm still a beginner. Thanks, Andy! I didn't know about the ? method.

Comment: I'd even go for `palindrome?` instead of `is_palindrome?`

Comment: That's odd, @Tamachan87, because you used ? methods [back in May](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586351/rubywarrior-level-4-cleaning-up-my-code-help).

Comment: Mark, you assume I know what I'm doing half the time. I took a few tips for RubyWarrior but I didn't know what it all did. I learn by doing.

Answer (score 2):

Not answering your question, but your use of booleans is horrendous. Remember boolean expressions return a boolean itself, you don't need another comparison. i.e.

```
def is_palindrome(n)
  if n.to_s == n.to_s.reverse
      true
  else
      false
  end
end
```

Should be:

```
def is_palindrome(n)
  n.to_s == n.to_s.reverse
end
```

And

```
while y > 100
  if is_palindrome(x * y) == true
```

Should be

```
while y > 100
  if is_palindrome(x * y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
# Find largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers

largest = 0
for i in 100..999
  for j in i..999
    product = j*i
    # Check for palindrome and determine largest
    largest = product.to_s == product.to_s.reverse && product > largest ? product : largest
  end
end
p largest
```